# UITabBarControllerの下に320×50の広告枠を設置する方法について(Swift)

Tags: swift

Objective-Cでのサイトがあったのですが、Swift版はなかったので質問してみました。
View上にUITabBarControllerを設置し、画面下(UITabBarController下)に320×50の広告を設置する方法について教えてください。

【補足】
Objective-Cでの方法はこちらのサイト(http://obc-fight.blogspot.jp/2012/07/uitabbarcontroller-under-advertisement.html)で確認したのですが、このサイトでいう「ViewController.m」における「TabBarControllerの初期化」と「表示」部分がよく理解できませんでした。

【再補足】
回答者様が教えてくださったコードを実装したところ、エラーは出なかったものの、
UITabBarControllerがコード通りに、50上に、表示されていませんでした。
(そのかわりTabBarと同じサイズの空白が出来ていました。)
どうすればいいでしょうか？

```js
import UIKit

class HomeView: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)   
    }
}
```

Comment: 最低、みつけたObjective-CのURLを提示し、それが、なぜ、Swiftで適用できないと感じたのか、説明が必要でしょう。

Comment: @らりん 質問の内容がはっきりしないので一旦クローズします。kmugitaniさんのコメントにあるように、Objective-C版のURLの提示、およびSwift版にする際にどこで躓いているかを明示してください。

Comment: 説明不十分で申し訳ございません。編集致しましたので見て頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: @らりん 改善ありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問の解決済みにした後に再補足を追加されたようですが、まだ回答を募集中でしょうか。でしたら、そのことを分かりやすくするために、回答につけたチェックマークを外しておくとよいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //TabBarControllerの初期化
>   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

は`let tabBarController = UITabBarController()`、

> //表示
>   [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

は`self.window?.addSubvew(tabBarController.view)`にあたるかと思います。

Comment: @pgrho様、回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ま、私が、あなたと同じ立場なら、そんな古ぼけた時代物のサイトなんか参照せずに

1 Single View Applicationで、project生成
2 話を簡単にするために、storyboardのUse Size Classのcheckをはずす
3 AdBannerViewをviewのした端にはりつける。
4 AdBannerViewにBottom Space to SuperViewを、ゼロにする。
5 AdBannerViewにHorizontal Center in ContainerViewをつける
6 ContainerViewを、AdBannerViewの上にはりつける。
7 ContainerViewには、自動で、ViewController（View)がついてくるが、これを選択して、削除する。
8 Storyboardの上に、TabBarControllerの部品を右下から引っ張り出して、貼り付ける。この時点で、storyboardの上には、ViewControllerと、TabBarControllerおよびそれについている２つのViewControllerが置かれている。
9 画面が小さくてみにくいだろうから、Zoomして、最初のViewControllerとTabBarControllerを見える状態にする。
10 その状態で、最初のViewControllerの真ん中をマウスカーソルで、さして、CTRLキーを押しながら、TabBarControllerの真ん中まで、マウス右ボタンを押したままでマウスカーソルを引きずり、マウス右ボタンを離す。
11 そうすると、segueのタイプは、何にするか？と聞かれるが、embedを選ぶ。
12 一番最初のViewController内部のContainerViewとAdBannerViewのVertical Spaceを、ゼロにする。

もちろん、これだけで、走らせたら、こけるが、それは、AdBannerViewに対して、glue codeを書いてやらないといけないだけの話。